# MTG: How does Devour work with abilites like Dragon Tempest

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

Suppose that I have [Dragon Broodmother](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189648), two dragon tokens, and [Dragon Tempest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=dragon%20tempest) on the battlefield.  [Dragon Broodmother](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189648) puts a 1/1 Dragon Token with Devour 2 on the battlefield and [Dragon Tempest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=dragon%20tempest) deals damage based on the number of dragons on the battlefield whenever a dragon enters.

My question is, if the new token summoned by [Dragon Broodmother](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189648) devours both dragon tokens, does [Dragon Tempest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=dragon%20tempest)'s ability count the devoured dragons in addition to [Dragon Broodmother](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189648) and the new token?  Are the devoured dragons still on the battlfield when the triggered ability resolves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Dragon Tempest's ability does **not** see the devoured Dragons when the Dragon token enters the battlefield. As you can see in the reminder text on Dragon Broodmother, the Devour ability says

> **As the token enters the battlefield**, you may sacrifice any number of creatures. **It enters the battlefield with** twice that many +1/+1 counters on it.

This means that Devour is a replacement effect ([CR 614.1c](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Replacement_Effect)), so it happens at the same time that the token enters the battlefield. By the time Dragon Tempest's ability triggers (and then resolves), the devoured dragons have already been sacrificed.

Comment: Ahh, I thought Devour was a triggered ability that would be put on the stack at the same time as Dragon Tempest's ability.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Luke, what you're thinking would have been templated with the word "When" instead of "As".